# Load Meteor.user() before Angular 2 starts

Tags: meteor, angular

I am starting a new Meteor - Angular2 application, but I am having troubles with checking the logged in user in my router.

This is my current `auth-guard.service.ts` file with an `AdminAuthGuard`, using `implements CanActivate`:

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    if (!Meteor.userId() || Meteor.user() != 'admin') {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

The problem is that when the page is loaded for the first time (or refreshed), the `Meteor.user()` function returns `undefined` and I can't find any way to load the user before the `canActivate()` function. I have also tried with a `Tracker.autorun()`, but the `canActivate()` can't be asynchronous. Also, `Meteor.users.find({})` does not work so I can't query the object manually.

What can I do? I can't find a solution anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Meteor.userId()` to find out that a user is logged in or not, But I am also working on it to find a solution for checking user role and I find out that you can use **Promise** or **Observable** to wait and find a user and check its role and than return a **True** or **False** condition.